# IntelliJ IDEA backspace and indention?

Tags: intellij-idea

Here's two scenarios:

Eclipse (or perhaps even other programs?):
If I indent, such as pressing tab or similar:
Step 1:  ( | is the caret )

```
public text(){
     |
}
```

Step 2: I press backspace:

```
 public text(){
 |
    }
```

See how one press of backspace moves back a whole indent since it's all empty space? Similarily, if I indent four times with TAB I'd press 4 backspaces, each moving one empty spaced indent.

Is this possible with IntelliJ because right now, I'm forced to spam the backspace key because it only moves back one step? As in, if I wanted to achieve the same result as in Step 2, I'd have to backspace like 4-5 times.

Comment: `SHIFT+TAB` will bring you back 1 indent, not sure if backspace is possible some way (haven't found it yet), but you can always post a feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/

Comment: Update: there's already a feature request for this, so you can vote on this one: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87318 or http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16731

Comment: Take a look at Hungry Backspace plugin: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=162

Answer (score 25):

Just in case someone else stumbles upon this in the future, this is now a standard option found at:

**Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys**.
Then under the **Backspace** section choose the **Unindent** option you like

Comment: probably necro'ing this, but
finally, this was bugging me for a long while

Comment: in Rider, you'd use *Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Typing Assistance -> Miscellaneous -> Unindent on Backspace : To nearest indent position* to get this behaviour

Answer (score 2):

When you press TAB in IntelliJ's Java editor by default you get 4 spaces instead of a single TAB character. You can change this behavior through File>Settings>Code Style>Java>Tabs and Indents. Just chek the 'Use tab character' check box.

Comment: ...but be aware that many believe this is a bad idea. (Many others believe it to be the best idea. It's a contentious issue.)

Comment: [Read about the contentiousness yourself!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this really handy plugin for intellij:  [hungry backspace](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/162?pr=)
It "eats" all the white spaces when you hit backspace!
Something close to that but not as good would be typing ctrl + backspace.

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding IntelliJ's backspace too aggressive, this will make it only delete one tab at a time (currently the default behavior deletes all the tabs on the current line and jumps the caret up to the end of the previous line).

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys

Unindent on Backspace: To nearest indent position

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> to unindent.

There is nothing in the preferences that will allow as simple as <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>.